# Cocos2d: Clipping Question

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

What is the recommended way to do basic clipping with cocos2d?

I am developing a tab control for an educational product and I want the items on a tab page to be clipped by that tab page.  So any CCSprites on the CCNode that IS the tab page should be clipped to that CCNode?

Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this topic:
[Cocos2d iPhone - Sprite cliping/mask/frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177751/cocos2d-iphone-sprite-cliping-mask-frame)

In a nutshell, you can't clip based on a CCSprite.  You need to create your own clipping mask and control it independently.