# In Cocos2d, how to create a layer that I can set its area size, and only its children that belongs in this area will be shown?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

Currently, no matter how big the layer is, when I add a child sprite to it, the sprite will be shown on the screen. But if I want to restrict the visible area of the layer and only show children that is inside this area, how can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at this topic [cocos2d-iphone-sprite-cliping-mask-frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177751/cocos2d-iphone-sprite-cliping-mask-frame)

Answer (score 1):

You should give **ClippingNode** a go here: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/01/cocos2d-gem-clippingnode/